# list hard drives within excel cell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script to make an hardware inventory of my PCs and exporting it within excel.

I have some problem listing hard drive.

Let's suppose one PC has two partions, C with 100 GB and E with 200 GB. I'd like to put drives within a single cell in this way with a carriage return.

```
C: 100 GB
E: 200 GB
```

If I want to create an excel file I can do something like this

```
$a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$a.Visible = $True
$b = $a.Workbooks.Add()
$c = $b.Worksheets.Item(1)
$c.Cells.Item(1,1) = "A value in cell A1."
```

and I know I can query wmi to list hard drive:

```
gwmi win32_logicaldisk | ? {$_.drivetype -eq 3} | select deviceid,@{Label="Disk GB"; Expression={[math]::truncate($_.Size / 1GB)}}
```

but I don't know how to get my desired output. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/File-Path/GetDriveInformation.htm answers you question

Answer (score 0):

How does this work?

```
$a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$a.Visible = $True
$b = $a.Workbooks.Add()
$c = $b.Worksheets.Item(1)
$label=gwmi win32_logicaldisk | select deviceid,@{Label="Disk GB";  Expression={"$([math]::truncate($_.Size / 1GB)) GB"}} | ft -auto -HideTableHeaders | out-string
$c.Cells.Item(1,1) = $label
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the returned drives from your WMI query and add the deviceid and "Disk GB" results to a string value.  Then you can write the resulting string value to the Excel cell.  One way to do this would be like this:

```
$a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$a.Visible = $True
$b = $a.Workbooks.Add()
$c = $b.Worksheets.Item(1)
$outputstring = ""
foreach ($drive in $driveinfo) {
    $outputstring += "$($drive.deviceid)  $($drive."Disk GB") GB`n"
}
$c.cells.item(1,1) = $outputstring
```